# Regex for Networking, IPs, ranges, subnets, Cidr

Tags: regex, networking

Given an input like this,  56.1.2.3 56.1.2.4 255.255.255.254 56.1.2.7-9 56.5.1.1 to 56.5.1.7, I need a regex that can pick out the what I have in brackets  [56.1.2.3] [56.1.2.4 255.255.255.254] [56.1.2.7-9] [56.5.1.1 to 56.5.1.7].

Here is what i have:

```
    private static final String IP_Address = "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\d";//56.1.2.3
private static final String IP_WithMask = "(\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+[255])(\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})"; //56.1.2.3 255.255.255.254
private static final String IP_CIDR = "(\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s*/)(\\d{1,3})"; //56.1.2.3/24 
private static final String IP_ADDRESS_Dash_Numeric_RANGE = "((\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s*-)(\\d{1,3}))";// 56.1.2.3-4
private static final String IP_ADDRESS_Dash_ADDRESS_RANGE = "((\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s*-\\s*)(\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3}))";//56.1.2.3-56.1.2.5
private static final String IP_ADDRESS_To_Numeric_RANGE = "(\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s*[T|t][O|o]\\s*)(\\d{1,3})";//56.1.2.3 to 255
private static final String IP_ADDRESS_To_ADDRESS_RANGE = "((\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3})(?:\\s*[T|t][O|o]\\s*)(\\d{1,3}.){3}(\\d{1,3}))";//56.1.2.3 to 56.1.3.5`
```

The Problem is that my regex can't pick out the difference between a single IP and the case of an IP followed by a mask (56.1.2.3 255.x.x.x). Same problem exists for the other types too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the below regex, works on all your cases.
See the comments in the formatted regex.
The way to decipher results is to test groups 3-6 for the type of IP.
All the components are captured, even the segment start.

Regex:

```
 (\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}\.(\d{1,3}))(?:(?:-|\s+to\s+)(\d{1,3}(?![\d\.]))|(?:-|\s*to\s+)(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})|\s+(25\d(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})|\s*/(\d{1,3}))?
```

Formatted ([with this app](http://www.regexformat.com)):

```
 (                             # (1), IP
      \d{1,3} 
      (?: \. \d{1,3} ){2}
      \.
      ( \d{1,3} )                   # (2), From segment
 )
 (?:
      (?: - | \s+ to \s+ )
      (                             # (3), Dash/To segment
           \d{1,3} 
           (?! [\d\.] )
      )
   |  
      (?: - | \s* to \s+ )
      (                             # (4), Dash/To range
           \d{1,3} 
           (?: \. \d{1,3} ){3}
      )
   |  
      \s+     
      (                             # (5), Mask
           25 \d 
           (?: \. \d{1,3} ){3}
      )
   |  
      \s* /     
      (                             # (6), Port
           \d{1,3} 
      )
 )?
```

Comment: my friend, that is a beautiful regex.

Comment: Thanks, hope you can do something with it.

Comment: Hey man, you did great on this question. Was hoping to get your input on this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509420/regex-to-catch-these-patterns-recursively