# Regex to catch these patterns recursively

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

```
    java.util.regex.Pattern ips
        = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}\\.(\\d{1,3}))(?:(?:-|\\s+to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?![\\d\\.]))|(?:-|\\s*to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s+(25\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s*\\/(\\d{1,3}))?");
```

Currently my Regex will accept the following types of IP address input, but only one input type at a time:

- ip: "47.1.2.3"
- range: "47.1.2.3-4"
- ip range: "47.1.2.3-47.1.2.4"
- ip to range: "47.1.2.3 to 4"
- ip to ip range: "47.1.2.3 to 47.1.2.4"
- ip CIDR: "47.1.2.4/32"
- ip Mask: "47.1.2.4 255.255.255.255"

I would like to modify my regex to accept combinations of these separated by a comma or space. Ideally the regex would have named capture groups as listed above to make handling easier.

I want the following to also be a valid input, but I want to be able to pull out the matches described above with named groups.

```
"47.1.2.3 to 4, 47.1.2.7, 47.1.3.9-47.1.3.19"
```

I'm attempting to use the regex to verify input into a text field. The following code is the textfield:

```
public class HostCollectionTextField extends JFormattedTextField implements CellEditor, MouseListener {

ArrayList listeners = new ArrayList();
HostCollection hc;
java.util.regex.Pattern ips
        = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}\\.(\\d{1,3}))(?:(?:-|\\s+to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?![\\d\\.]))|(?:-|\\s*to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s+(25\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s*\\/(\\d{1,3}))?");

public HostCollectionTextField() {
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.hc = new HostCollection();

    this.setFormatterFactory(new AbstractFormatterFactory() {

        @Override
        public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField tf) {
            RegexFormatter f = new RegexFormatter(ips);
            return f;
        }
    });
    this.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocListener(this));
    addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (stopCellEditing()) {
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

//class methods....
}

This is the RegexFormatter Class:

```
public class RegexFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {

protected java.util.regex.Matcher matcher;

public RegexFormatter(java.util.regex.Pattern regex) {
    setOverwriteMode(false);
    matcher = regex.matcher(""); // create a Matcher for the regular expression
}

public Object stringToValue(String string) throws java.text.ParseException {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    matcher.reset(string); // set 'string' as the matcher's input

    if (!matcher.matches()) // Does 'string' match the regular expression?
    {
        throw new java.text.ParseException("does not match regex", 0);
    }

    // If we get this far, then it did match.
    return super.stringToValue(string); // will honor the 'valueClass' property
}
```

}

Comment: But well it accepts the list also: https://regex101.com/r/jS2sD6/1

Comment: Added more code to explain. I'm using it as input verification. Once a comma is typed, my input is no longer valid.

Comment: Rather than one "super dooper regular expression of totally ridiculously insane complexity", I would recommend splitting your input on commas, and validating each separate field separately. Regular expressions are nice, and all, but they're not the ultimate swiss army knife of programming that so many people seem to think they are, and trying to force them into that role often has undesired and surprising effects...

Comment: like this: https://regex101.com/r/jS2sD6/2 ?

Comment: Also I believe this task should not be done with regex: even on this stage it is huge and still failing basic test: https://regex101.com/r/jS2sD6/3

Comment: You must use comma as the list separator because if you use space the "ip mask" case can't be distinguished from a list of two simple IPs.  What you're trying to do is an **insane** use of regex--and it probably won't _ever_ work to boot.  I've been doing regexes for 30+ years, write then daily, have used them to parse IP addresses, and I would _never_ try to do this.  What you're trying to do needs a simple tokenizer layer that splits first, then smaller regexes to match the given token sequence.

Comment: So you are suggesting using my document listener to split the input on comma if it exists, the use the regex to verify each substring? My goal was to use the InputVerifyer to validate user Input in real time. Since it only takes regex, I assumed regex could handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip parts are pretty unique, there should be no problem with
overlapping parts during a match using whitespace and/or comma as separator.

You probably need two versions of the same regex.
One to *validate*, one to extract.

The one to extract is just your original regex used in a global match.
This is used after a validation.

The validation one is below. It matches multiple ip parts at once using
the anchors `^$` with the original quantified regex embedded between using
the required separator `[\s,]+`.

Not sure if this will work for your validation code, but if entering 
a single ip part now, works, then this should.

*Validation regex:*

`"^(?:\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}\\.\\d{1,3}(?:(?:-|\\s+to\\s+)\\d{1,3}(?![\\d\\.])|(?:-|\\s*to\\s+)\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3}|\\s+25\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3}|\\s*\\/\\d{1,3})?(?:[\\s,]*$|[\\s,]+))+$"`

Formatted:

```
 ^     
 (?:
      \d{1,3} 
      (?: \. \d{1,3} ){2}
      \.
      \d{1,3} 
      (?:
           (?: - | \s+ to \s+ )
           \d{1,3} 
           (?! [\d\.] )
        |  
           (?: - | \s* to \s+ )
           \d{1,3} 
           (?: \. \d{1,3} ){3}
        |  
           \s+ 
           25 \d 
           (?: \. \d{1,3} ){3}
        |  
           \s* \/
           \d{1,3} 
      )?

      (?:
           [\s,]* $ 
        |  
           [\s,]+  
      )
 )+
 $
```

---

**edit:** add group names to extraction regex.

```
 # "(?<IP>\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}\\.(?<From_Seg>\\d{1,3}))(?:(?:-|\\s+to\\s+)(?<To_Seg>\\d{1,3}(?![\\d\\.]))|(?:-|\\s*to\\s+)(?<To_Range>\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s+(?<Mask>25\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s*/(?<Port>\\d{1,3}))?"

 (?<IP>                        # (1), IP
      \d{1,3} 
      (?: \. \d{1,3} ){2}
      \.
      (?<From_Seg> \d{1,3} )        # (2), From segment
 )
 (?:
      (?: - | \s+ to \s+ )
      (?<To_Seg>                    # (3), Dash/To segment
           \d{1,3} 
           (?! [\d\.] )
      )
   |  
      (?: - | \s* to \s+ )
      (?<To_Range>                  # (4), Dash/To range
           \d{1,3} 
           (?: \. \d{1,3} ){3}
      )
   |  
      \s+     
      (?<Mask>                      # (5), Mask
           25 \d 
           (?: \. \d{1,3} ){3}
      )
   |  
      \s* /     
      (?<Port>                      # (6), Port
           \d{1,3} 
      )
 )?
```

Comment: It does validate, but is there a way to pull the named groups. i.e. determine what kind of match it is with a named capture group?

Comment: I was confident you'd have the answer btw. You should be the official regex expert for Stack

Comment: @JamieSnipes - Ok, added group names to the regex. You'd have to research Java regex to access the capture names in the matcher. I think its the same as the numbering for the most part.